# MVC Input name wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc, input, mvc-editor-templates, editortemplates

I want to use a (bootstrap) modal to show a translationdialog but it's giving a wrong name.
In the browser sourcecode it shows *NameTranslations.[0].Translatio*n while it have to be *NameTranslations[0].Translation* (without the dot between NameTranslation and the [i]).

Some code :

Views/Shared/EditorTemplate/**Translation**.cshtml

```
@model List<Data.ViewModels.Shared.TranslationViewModel>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Translation)
}
```

**Create**.cshtml

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.NameTranslations,"Translation")
```

BrowserResult

```
<input id="NameTranslations__0__Translation" name="NameTranslations.[0].Translation" type="text" value="">
```

Everything work greats except the name convention is wrong. If I delete the dot in the browsercode, it is well posted in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with a ViewData

**Create**.cshtml

```
@model List<Data.ViewModels.Shared.TranslationViewModel>
@{
    var ModelName = ViewData["ModelName"];
}
```

Partial View: Views/Shared/**_Translation**.cshtml

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    var LanguageID = ModelName + "[" + i + "].LanguageID";
    var TranslationName= ModelName + "[" + i + "].Translation";

    <input type="hidden" name="@LanguageID" value="@Model[i].LanguageID" />
    <input type="text" name="@TranslationName" value="@Model[i].Translation" />
    <br />
}
```

I think it isn't the best way to do it but if there's a change in a ViewModel, you can replace it in one place (partial) instead of several.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the name attribute by specifying explicit value using new { name = yourdynamicName }

Comment: I tried this                         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Translation, new { name = Model[i].Translation }) 

But the result is the same

Comment: Then try to assign the value into local variable or frame the local variable value as per your requirement.Like var tempName = Model[i].Translation or tempName=Model[i].Translation+"_"+i and assign the tempName into name attribute.If still not working try to edit the value at runtime and see whether edited value is assigned or not

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes to the `Translation` template to be an editor template for a single entity only:

```
@model Data.ViewModels.Shared.TranslationViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Translation)
...
```

and iterate through the collection in the main view instead:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.NameTranslations.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NameTranslations[i], "Translation")
}
```

Comment: This won't work great because I want to make a dialog with a table in it.. But it's a possible solution if i find nothing else :)

Comment: If you need this in dialog, use a partial view instead of a view.